# Is it possible to detect support of CSS3 functions like attr() or url() using Modernizr?

Tags: css, modernizr

I've been searching for a while for a Modernizr test for CSS functions like [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/attr), but I couldn't find anything. Is there a way to test these features?

Comment: Do you mean CSS *selectors* like `attr`, rather than functions?

Comment: For what it's worth, the only browser without the `attr` selector that you're likely to encounter today are IE6. Even IE7 supports it. Given that, you'd be justified in just not supporting IE6 at all if you want to use `attr`.

Comment: To add to Spudley's comment, here's a link to one of my favorite sites, with CSS selector (and more) compatibility tables: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/index.html. I realize that has nothing to do with Modernizr, but may help. Additionally, it shouldn't be too hard to write your own javascript to test for the attr selector, similar to what you'd like Modernizr to do.

Comment: I meant the new attr() function. For example: `` #mydiv{content:attr(data-icon)}`` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/attr

Comment: @Spudley: `attr()` is a function, not a selector. There is no such selector called `attr` - unless you're confusing that with an *attribute selector*.

Comment: @BoltClock - yes, I was confusing it with the selector. I mis-read the question. (that said, the original version of the question wasn't quite as clear on what he meant :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS functions vary a great deal in their use, and count as values rather than properties or selectors, so there isn't a generic Modernizr test for them. However, [it does provide feature detection for some specific functions](http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-css):

- [RGBA](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color) and [HSLA](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#hsla-color) color values: `Modernizr.rgba` and `Modernizr.hsla`
- [Gradients](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#gradients): `Modernizr.cssgradients`
- [Transforms](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms): `Modernizr.csstransforms` for 2D transforms and `Modernizr.csstransforms3d` for 3D transforms

Modernizr does not provide feature detection for `url()` because that has been around forever and every browser supports it fully.

It also does not provide feature detection for `attr()`, but for what it's worth, every browser that does implement `attr()` (IE8+ and other browsers) only implements it as defined in [CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html). As of 2013, no implementation exists for the version defined in [Values and Units level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr-notation).

Note that CSS2.1 `attr()` is only usable with the `content` property on the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, which Modernizr *does* offer feature detection for in the form of `Modernizr.generatedcontent`.